# How to return data from web service in common js module

Tags: javascript, webservice-client, titanium-alloy, commonjs, titanium-modules

I am writing a mobile app using Titanium Alloy. I am not understanding how to write a module that would return an object. The version that I have written returns "undefined". 
 Any help will be appreciated!

This how I consume the module in index.js

```
    var ResArgs = require("WebData").GetItemDetails(args.barcode, args.type);
    Ti.API.info("Received data from WebGetData: " + ResArgs);
```

This is the actual WebData.js module

```
exports.GetItemDetails = function(code, type) {
    var url = "http://url/" + code + "/" + type;
    var arg = null || {};
    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        // function called when the response data is available
        onload : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Received text from service: " + this.responseText);
            return this.responseText;
        },
        // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
        onerror : function(e) {
            Ti.API.debug(e.error);
            alert('error: ' + e.error);
        },
        timeout : 5000 // in milliseconds
    });
    client.open("GET", url);
    // Send the request.
    client.send();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a callback

```
exports.GetItemDetails = function(code, type, _callback) {
  var url = "http://url/" + code + "/" + type;
  var arg = null || {};
  var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    // function called when the response data is available
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Received text from service: " + this.responseText);
        _callback && _callback({success : true, data : this.responseText});
    },
    // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
    onerror : function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error: ' + e.error);
        _callback && _callback({success : false, error:e.error});
    },
    timeout : 5000 // in milliseconds
  });
  client.open("GET", url);
  // Send the request.
  client.send();
};
```

you would then call the code like this

```
var ResArgs = require("WebData");
ResArgs.GetItemDetails(args.barcode, args.type, function(_response){
  if ( _response.success ) {
     Ti.API.info("Received data from WebGetData: " + _response.data);
  } else {
     Ti.API.error("ERROR from WebGetData: " + _response.error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code `GetItemDetails` does not have a `return` statement and thus correctly return `undefined`. As the internally used APIs do use callbacks the code cannot be written this this explicit way, instead your `GetItemDetails` method would probably need a callback as a parameter which you call in `onload` or/and `onerror`.

I hope that explains the issue.